# Compiling my C++ code for ARM Architecture

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, java-native-interface, arm

I am a java developer. I have some C++ code to make some system realted calls. This code is compiled on Intel 32-bit platform using GCC (I have make files) and it works fine on regular Intel based 32-bit linux machine. Now I need to run this on a linux OS running on Marvell ARM processor. When I load the shared objects in java I get the following error.

**cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform)**

Please tell me how to resolve this issue. I looked at the GCC options and I found one option to specify the architecture (-march=armv5) and I can't compile with that option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a cross-compiler, or just re-compile on the Linux ARM system.

Comment: Visit http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/hg/crosstool-ng/ which supplies a suite for creating cross-compilers for many host and target platforms

Comment: Also, crosstool-ng homepage: http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/projects/crosstool

Comment: @Hasturkun: Already mentioned that!?

Comment: @rstevens: No, you linked to the mercurial repository, Hasturkun linked to the project homepage.

Comment: get the codesourcery compiler and cross compile your program (replace gcc with arm-none-linux-gcc, etc in the makefile).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need more than just a switch, you need a cross-compiler. You can make your own, but probably the easiest way is :

- Find the development tools for your board. It probably comes with a development kit that includes a cross-compilation toolchain
- If you don't have these, you can try to install a precompiled cross-compilation like the ones provided freely by CodeSourcery

Then you have to make the location of your toolchain (look for something like arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc) available in your path.

Cross compiling simple project is then easy, just override the CC variable in your Makefile :

```
CROSS = arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
CC = $(CROSS)gcc
LD = $(CROSS)ld
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the -mcpu=armv5 switch for gcc.

Comment: -mcpu is deprecated. if I use -march=armv5, i get the following error. error: bad value (armv5) for -march= switch

Comment: In most cases (this case included) you need a cross compiler that targets the ARM environment and the compiler that produced the intel code will not know how to also compile arm code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's written on http://elinux.org/RPi_Software#ARM:

```
-Ofast -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -march=armv6zk -mtune=arm1176jzf-s
```